# How to detect iPhone/Android awake from sleep with javascript

Tags: javascript, sockets, web-applications, websocket

Im building a website/webapp that uses sockets.io

Currently if the user is using safari on an iphone for example and they lock the screen (goes black) My socket connection is closed. This is good, I want this.

However when they unlock the screen (or awake from sleep). I would like to detect this event with javascript so I can reconnect my socket.

Is this possible?? Google isn't turning much up on the subject.

Comment: What kind of solution did you end up with?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("pageshow", function(){
    alert("page shown");
}, false);
</script>
```