# detecting sleep mode on mobile devices in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, mobile-devices

How can I detect if a Phone or Tablet is going into sleeping mode (when the user clicks the button to disable the screen or if the system is automatically doing that, when some times is gone). 
Is there some kind of event like `onbeforesleep`,...

thx in advance

Comment: I assume this is for some sort of saveBeforeSleep() function?

Comment: For a mobile web page or webview app?

Comment: check `onblur` and `onfocus` event

Comment: this is for a web page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect iPhone/Android awake from sleep with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347351/how-to-detect-iphone-android-awake-from-sleep-with-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, it seems to work (4 upvotes)

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("pageshow", function(){
    alert("page shown");
}, false);
</script>
```

Source: [How to detect iPhone/Android awake from sleep with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347351/how-to-detect-iphone-android-awake-from-sleep-with-javascript)

Comment: This didn't get triggered when returning from sleep mode, unfortunately.